# Konvajs - findone() function behaviour has changed between 2.0.2 and 2.4.2

Tags: konvajs

I have a piece of code that worked just fine with Konvajs.2.0.2.

```
var startCity = mainStage.findOne('#0');
```

It would return the node with the ID=0. Works like a charm in the 2.0.2 version.

But know when I udpate to 2.4.2, this does not find the node anymore and returns a JS error (object undefined). It works for any other IDs on the map (2,3,4,etc).

I checked and printed all the node and there is definitely one with ID=0;

Any information or clue on what could have changed in the `find()` or `findone()` function between those 2 releases? Is it something like you cannot have an ID=0 anymore maybe?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you make a demo? Probably it makes sense to add an issue on the GitHub for that. https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior was slightly changed.

Now `id` cannot have values that `== null` (like empty string or 0).

To fix the issue you can convert number 0 to string `"0"`. Or use another id.

Comment: Great, makes sense now. Thank you !

Comment: Good enhancement. Just thinking aloud, given there is code out there that will fall foul of this, as per the OP case, would it be worth adding a warning at the point that the null id is assigned ? Something like 'Warning: id must not be null or zero.'

Comment: @VanquishedWombat yeah, probably we should add that warning.